# Adding different page headers in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word

I am facing some difficulties while adding different page headers to different pages in my document.

I am dividing my document into several chapters, each chapter should have its own header and footer. I have merged the files into one single document through insert > object and text from file. Now I want to have different headers and footers for each chapter.

I tried to check Different odd or even and different first page and choose the option that the section starts at a new page. But, still I can't have different headers for each chapter.

Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a section break.  When you have a section break, the headers and footers can be different in each section.

Answer (score 0):

I had an option of "different first page" while editing a header (under design menu). That allowed me to create new page header.  However, I had to do this for every page